# Chaining Bash Statements

Tags: bash

I've been struggling with this for some time but my current bash statements look like:

```
trim() {
    local var="$*"
    var="${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"   # remove leading whitespace characters
    var="${var%"${var##*[![:space:]]}"}"   # remove trailing whitespace characters
    echo -n "$var"
}
```

with

```
CV=trim `$(cat somejson | grep '\"fdsaf\"' | sed 's/  "fasdf": "\(.*\)",/\1/')`
```

This fails because I believe

`$(cat somejson | grep '\"fdsaf\"' | sed 's/  "fasdf": "\(.*\)",/\1/')`

gets interpreted as a bash command and an error is thrown.

Instead, I refactored this into

```
CV=$(cat somejson | grep '\"dasf\"' | sed 's/  "fasd": "\(.*\)",/\1/')
NEW_CV=$(trim $UNTRIMMED_PROD_NAME)
```

Is there a cleaner way to chain these two commands together? My refactored approach looks messy.

Comment: You don't need to specify `echo -n` -- bash automatically trims trailing newlines for command substitutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `CV` and `UNTRIMMED_PROD_NAME` are the same variable (typo) then yes, just nest the `$()` bits.

```
NEW_CV=$(trim $(grep '\"dasf\"' somejson | sed 's/  "fasd": "\(.*\)",/\1/'))
```

---

Your original `` CV=trim `....` `` was not working correctly because you forgot the outer `$()` and the shell saw that as:

Set `CV=trim` in the environment of the command to be run from the results of running the output of the `cat somejson | grep '\"fdsaf\"' | sed 's/  "fasdf": "\(.*\)",/\1/'` command (yes running the output of, you have *two* executions there).

```
CV=trim `$(cat somejson | grep '\"fdsaf\"' | sed 's/  "fasdf": "\(.*\)",/\1/')`
```

first expands the inner command `$()` and gets a result and ends up with

```
CV=trim `cat-grep-sed-result`
```

then expands the backtick command execution (the `cat-grep-sed-result` string taken as a command) which is probably throwing an error and resulting in an empty string and ending up with

```
CV=trim
```

which is then processed as an assignment.

Comment: I fixed up the literal backticks, but I don't know if I kept your original intent. Please re-edit if necessary.

Comment: @glennjackman Basically right, thanks. And you taught (or possibly reminded me) about the doubling backticks thing too.

Comment: Maybe also advise on converting `grep foo | sed bar` to just `sed '/foo/bar'`